# AWS Amplify project failed to update due to error to (unmodified) resource

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have an AWS amplify project including a lambda (in python) and a related apigateway; keep in mind that the lambda is up and working, and when I perform `amplify pull`, everything go smoothly.

Suddenly, whenever I perform change to the code of my lambda (the index.py file, and nothing else) and try to run `amplify push -y` I obtain a message reporting that the resource I did not modify (the gateway) failed to update because of two parameters (the arn and name of the function) not being in the template. I'm struggling to understand:

- why my lambda is failing to be deployed due to something I did not change;
- how the gateway was altered by the changes in the .py file of the function in the first place;
- how I'm supposed to fix the situation.

Thanks in advance.